# Azure API Management - determine if response was served from cache

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are using a `<cache-lookup>` policy in the `<inbound>` block (with an external Redis). Is it possible to execute a policy - to be specific, I would like to write a `<trace>`when the cache lookup was a hit and the response is served from cache?

Today we have this:

```
<inbound>
  <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="external">
     <vary-by-query-parameter>xyz</vary-by-query-parameter>
  </cache-lookup>
```

Is something like this possible? (pseudo code)

```
  <choose>
    <when condition="cache-lookup == true">
       <trace>
         <message>This request is served from Redis cache!</message>
       </trace>
    </when>
  </choose>
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to some research, it seems there isn't a variable or status for us to judge if the request is served from Redis cache or the backend server. The `<cache-lookup>` policy wraps the functions connect with Redis, I don't think we can know where the request is served from. And as you mentioned the code is pseudo, I don't think the code `<when condition="cache-lookup == true">` can work.

For this requirement, I think you can just ask azure develop team for this feature on [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) page.